# Scale Data to log-normal. Is my approach right?

Tags: python, numpy, normalization

I have a one dimensional Array where the datas are between 1 and 500.
The distribution of the data looks like log-normal.

What i want is to resample the array to log(data)

i am not sure about which function to use:

[numpy.log](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.log.html) or [numpy.log1p](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.log1p.html)

my rescale Function looks like this now, but i am not sure if its right:

```
def ScaleData(dataset):
    datas = []
    for x in np.nditer(dataset):
        a = np.log(x)
        datas.append(a)
    return np.array(datas)
```

Test:

```
38, 48, 39, 83, 64, 57
goes to:
3.63758616,  3.87120101,  3.66356165,  4.41884061, 4.15888308,  4.04305127
```

Is that right?

Comment: If working with numpy, try to avoid for loops. `np.log` e.g. works on numpy arrays.

Comment: 1. I think Log-Normal and Log-Log is used for 2D arrays where one dimension is showed using normal numbers and the other using logarithmic.  2. Normalization means scaling your data so that they vary from 0 to 1.

Comment: @Sosel 
Thanks for your advise. i have an another question. how can i Transform the np.log(dataset) back to the normal value?

Comment: @Ehsan 
Thanks for your advise. i have an another question. how can i Transform the np.log(dataset) back to the normal value?

Comment: Maybe you can use 'np.power(10,your_list)' or 'np.float_power...'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- if you want to fit your data to a log normal distribution : you should use  scipy.stats.lognorm.fit(listofdata) and check the quality of the fitting with a Kalmogorov Smirnov test : scipy.stats.kstest
- if you want to transform your data np.log(dataset) should be enough.

Best

Comment: Thanks for your advise. i have an another question. how can i Transform the np.log(dataset) back to the normal value?

Comment: how to use scipy.stats.lognorm.fit to data from csv? The data is open using pandas